# display selected date from date piker in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use a datepiker in react native to consolelog the piked date when I click on the  Button i want to console.log(slected) selected date

```
  const [text, setTextname] = useState();
const [mydate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [displaymode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [isDisplayDate, setShow] = useState(false);
    const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || mydate;
    let date = moment(selectedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    console.log('dadad', date);
    setTextname(date);

    setShow(false);
  };
  const showMode = currentMode => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const displayDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  }; 


  function getdata() {
  
    console.log('sdsds', text);
 
  }

<Button onPress={displayDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
        {isDisplayDate && (
          <DateTimePicker
            testID="dateTimePicker"
            value={mydate}
            mode={displaymode}
            is24Hour={true}
            display="default"
            onChange={text => changeSelectedDate()}
            // onChange={changeSelectedDate}
          />
        )}
<View style={styles.buttonw}>
        <Button
          color="#7743DB"
          title="Lets Go"
          type="submit"
          onPress={() => getdata()}
        />
      </View>
```

i have displayed the datepiker but i am not able to pick a  date and pass it to getdata

Comment: @Adnan sayed pls check this question

Comment: hey please add the output of console statements also the commented onChange function is correct

Comment: `LOG  dadad 14/12/2022
 LOG  dadad 06/12/2022`

Comment: fisrt i am gettting the slected date then it is getting replaced by current date

Comment: `LOG  sdsds 06/12/2022` when i click submit i am getting todays date

Comment: Its because you are using 2 state variable to update date. Remove the text variable and just use mydate variable to update date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
const [text, setTextname] = useState();
```

Replace in function changeSelectedDate

```
setTextname(date);
```

with

```
setDate(date);
```

and

```
const currentDate = selectedDate || mydate
```

by

```
const currentDate = selectedDate
```

and lastly

```
function getdata() {

console.log('sdsds',mydate);

}
```

changes to function

```
 const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {

setDate(selectedDate);

setShow(false);
  };

function getdata() {
let date = moment(mydate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log('sdsds',date);
}
```

Comment: `value prop must be an instance of date object`  iam getting thiss error

Comment: try last block of answer replace the functions with my code.\

Answer (score 0):

You have to set date on setDate state in your change date function.

```
setDate(date);----->add this
setTextname(date);
```